# Open a tab from dropdown menu within the same page

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, nav

Is there a way to link an item from a dropdown menu on a sidebar to a tab within your webpage?

My page 2 dropdown located on my side navbar shows different tabs within page 2, but when a tab is selected from the dropdown the page is just redirected to the top of page 2.

```
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <hr class="sidebar">
            <ul class="nav navbar">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="page1.html">PAGE 1</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" href="page2.html" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">PAGE 2</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#tab-1">One</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#tab-2">Two</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="tab-3">Three</a>
                        </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="page2.html">PAGE 3</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="page3.html">PAGE 4</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </hr>       
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'a tab'? `dropdown-item` or `nav-item`?

Comment: Are you using any framework ?

Comment: as apena asked, You're going to have to explain what you mean by "a tab". There are several things people mean when they use the word "tab" when talking about web pages & browsers.  and if it's something in your page, _show the markup for it._

Comment: @apena  My website has four pages that are accessible by a side navbar. I've put dropdown-items within my PAGE 2 nav-item located within the sidebar. These dropdown-items are nav-items are located on PAGE 2. The sidebar nav-items work just fine directing between the HTML pages, but the dropdown-items when clicked don't open the tabs they correspond to on page 2. I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing within the href or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try puting the page you want to navigate to in front of the anchor in the `href` of your `dropdown-items`.

So change:

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#tab-1">One</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#tab-2">Two</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="tab-3">Three</a>
```

To:

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="page2.html#tab-1">One</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="page2.html#tab-2">Two</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="page2.html#tab-3">Three</a>
```